# Вопрос по массивам JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Очень нужна помощь. У меня есть 4 массивы, в каждом по 4 элемента. Как мне взять с каждого массива по 2 рандомных числа и засунуть в новые массивы?

```
let a = ['laptop' , 'PC', 'PS4', 'PSP'];
let b = ['lamp', 'sofa' , 'car' , 'pen'];
let c = ['tablet' , 'window' , 'jym', 'training'];
let d = ['cat','dog','parrot','leg'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
let a = ['laptop', 'PC', 'PS4', 'PSP'];
let b = ['lamp', 'sofa', 'car', 'pen'];
let c = ['tablet', 'window', 'jym', 'training'];
let d = ['cat', 'dog', 'parrot', 'leg'];

let output = [].concat(...[a, b, c, d].map(a => a.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, 2)));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для начала разберемся как получить рандомные числа, в этом нам поможет *Math.random()*
Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Создадим функцию, которая позволит нам работать с *Math.random()* более удобно

```
function rnd(min, max) {
  // получаем случайное число от (min-0.5) до (max+0.5)
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand); //округляем к ближайшему целому числу.
}
```

Теперь мы сможем вытащить из нужного нам массива случайный элемент и засунуть в новый массив

```js
let a = ['laptop' , 'PC', 'PS4', 'PSP'];
let b = ['lamp', 'sofa' , 'car' , 'pen'];
function rnd(min, max) {
  let rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1);
  return Math.round(rand);
}
var list = [];
list.push(a[rnd(0, a.length-1)]); // получаем случайный элемент и вносим его в массив list
list.push(b[rnd(0, a.length-1)]);

console.log(list)
```